# Retrieving e-mails from virtual server using c#

Tags: c#, email, virtual-server

I am trying to create an appication, that collects the emails, which are sent to my virtual server, using c#. I created a virtual domain using IIS 6 , though in the long run my application should be IIS 7 compatible, too. I do not want to directly collect the e-mails from the drop folder, which is used by my virtual server.

I am sure there is a way of doing this, but can't seem so find it.

Thanks for your input and thoughts!

**Further specifics:**
I have a smtp virtual server on a Windows Server 2008. e-mails are sent to a registered local domain (mydomain.de; Type local, alias) by a seperate program (e.g. Thunderbird). What I want to do is not forward these e-mails, but use a c# application to retrieve the e-mails.

One way of doing this would be to access the dropbox directory (default: c:\inetpub\mailroot), readout the eml-file, delete it from the directory and work with the file. This does not seem like a good solution, though.

What I would like to do is something like to following:

`Connect("mydomain.de");
GetMessages();
Disconnect();`

Thanks again for your thoughts and help!

Comment: this is too vague IMO. if you can list the specifics. and look at [Ask]